# How do I set Internet Proxy on Apache Commons Mail Api?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-email

I would like to send email using a custom proxy on apache commons email api because I'm connected to the internet through a proxy server.

I've tried using the common ways of setting proxies in java but it doesn't seem to work. e.g

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true" ); 
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "6056");
```

And

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true" );     
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");     
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "6056");`
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
  Email mail = ....

mail.getSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socks.host", "my.socks.host");
  ...

  mail.send();
```